# Angular UI-grid not sorting by date

Tags: angular-ui-grid

I am using UI-grid, and I have a bunch of JS date objects like so:

```
"dob": new Date('1942-11-19')
```

I want to be able to filter the column by date when you click the "sort ascending/descending" buttons. As such, I have set the `colDef` up like so:

```
      {
        field: 'dob'
        , displayName: 'D.O.B.'
        , width: '130'
        , editableCellTemplate: '<div><form name="inputForm"><input type="INPUT_TYPE" ng-class="\'colt\' + col.uid" ui-grid-editor ng-model="MODEL_COL_FIELD" style="border-bottom-color: #74B3CE; border-bottom-width: 2px;"></form></div>'
        , headerCellClass: $scope.highlightFilteredHeader
        , cellTemplate: '<div class="ui-grid-cell-contents" >{{grid.getCellValue(row, col)| date:\'MM-dd-yyyy\'}}</div>'
        , cellFilter: 'date'
        , type: 'date'
      },
```

however, the column simply does not sort correctly. I even tried to set up a function to sort it from an external button like so:

```
      function mostRecent(){
        console.log('clicked mostRecent');
        $scope.gridApi.grid.sortColumn(
          $scope.gridApi.grid.getColumn('dob'), uiGridConstants.DESC
        );
        $scope.gridApi.grid.notifyDataChange(uiGridConstants.dataChange.ALL); //this line updates the rest of the columns accordingly
      };
```

But it also causes a mish-mush sort that is not correct. Does anyone know what the issue is? I thought it might have to do with my `cellTemplate`, but after removing the template, there wasn't a difference...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes you are right, ui-grid doesn't support sorting of Date type columns.

However you can define a `sortingAlgorithm` in the [`columnDef`](http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/api/ui.grid.class:GridOptions.columnDef).

Here is how your column definition should look like:

```
...

columnDefinition.sortingAlgorithm = function (firstDateString, secondDateString) {
  var dateFormat = 'YYYY-MM-DD';
  return function (firstDateString, secondDateString, dateFormat) {
    if (!firstDateString && !secondDateString) {
      return 0;
    }

    if (!firstDateString) {
      return 1;
    }

    if (!secondDateString) {
      return -1;
    }

    var firstDate = $window.moment(firstDateString, dateFormat);
    if (!firstDate.isValid()) {
      throw new Error('Invalid date: ', firstDateString);
    }

    var secondDate = $window.moment(secondDateString, dateFormat);
    if (!firstDate.isValid()) {
      throw new Error('Invalid date: ', secondDateString);
      }

    if (firstDate.isSame(secondDate)) {
      return 0;
    } else {
      return firstDate.isBefore(secondDate) ? -1 : 1;
    }
  };
};

...
```

Please note that in this example [Moment.js](http://momentjs.com) is used. It is a very useful library so you might probably find also another place in your project where to use it.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I tried it, it does not seem to have an effect on the sort unfortunately. I am still getting the same, unsorted results

Comment: @IWI can you create Plunker or JSFiddle?

Comment: You were actually right. I'm a fool and just noticed that my dates were strings and not date objects....

Answer (score 0):

```
$scope.gridOptions = { 
  data: 'gridData',
   columnDefs: [
    {field: 'name', displayName: 'Name'}, 
    {field:'age', 
     displayName:'Birth Date',
     sortFn: function (aDate, bDate) {
       var a=new Date(aDate);
       var b=new Date(bDate);
       if (a < b) {
         return -1;
       }
       else if (a > b) {
         return 1;
       }
       else {
         return 0;
       }
     }
       }]
};
```

Try this 
http://plnkr.co/edit/0VD3X5YvuNSWAZlig95X?p=info

reference :
https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-grid/issues/222

Answer (score 0):

You can define the Sorting Algorithm for the date fields in UI Grid like below

```
columnDefs: [
{
                    field: 'DateFrom', displayName: 'From',
                    sortingAlgorithm: function (aDate, bDate, rowA, rowB, direction) {
                        var a = new Date(moment(aDate, "DD-MM-YYYY").format("YYYY-MM-DD"));
//here DD-MM-YYYY is the current format in which the dates are returned 
                        var b = new Date(moment(bDate, "DD-MM-YYYY").format("YYYY-MM-DD"));
                        if (a < b) {
                            return -1;
                        }
                        else if (a > b) {
                            return 1;
                        }
                        else {
                            return 0;
                        }
                    }

                }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

We can sort the ui-grid column containing date field in a simplest way.
Make use of cellTemplate in this way:

```
{
  name: "Date",
  field: 'date',
  cellTemplate:'<div>{{row.entity.date | date:"dd/MM/yyyy"}}</div>' 
 },
```

So, you can choose any format for date, for eg. date:"dd-MM" etc.